# emacs rjsx mode fix highlighting

Tags: javascript, emacs, eslint

Is there some way to tell rjsx mode that the jest and BDD keywords (shown in orange) are really OK?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rjsx-mode` extends `js2-mode` which allows you to declare global externs through the customizable `js2-global-externs` variable.  If you are using `rjsx-mode` in your spec files, you could customize that variable in one of your `rjsx` or `js`/`js2` mode hooks, eg.

```
(setq js2-global-externs
      (cl-remove-duplicates
       (append
        '("describe" "it" "expect" "beforeEach" "afterEach" "spyOn")       
        js2-global-externs)
       :test #'string=))
```

although you may prefer to use the customize interface.  Setting this will make those functions recognized in all js/rjsx buffers, however.

You could localize the changes to just spec files by setting the variable locally in a minor mode hook (eg. `jest-mode` or create your own mode for spec files).

Comment: perfect.. thanks! I added: `(use-package rjsx-mode :config (setq js2-global-externs ...))`